# How to set the default RequestFormat for a WCF ServiceContract?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, webhttpbinding

I'm writing a web service that has a lot of methods. They are all set up similar to the following:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "x/y/z")]
    void someMethod(int x, int y, int z);
```

What I want to do is just set the default `BodyStyle` / `RequestFormat` / `ResponseFormat` all in the web.config file. Now, I know I can do this:

```xml
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
      <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Bare" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

But there doesn't seem to be an attribute for the RequestFormat. How can I set the default `RequestFormat` to JSON?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Request types are [automatically interpreted by WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510.aspx), you don't need to specify a default `RequestFormat` for your service operation.

If you are trying to enforce the supported request format, see [this related SO post on enforcing request content types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1227476/175679).

**Note:** it doesn't make sense to assign a `RequestFormat` for a `WebGet` operation. By definition, a `WebGet` cannot contain a `Body` which is where the JSON format would exist. A better example here would be `WebInvoke`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So as long as the body specifies "application/json" format, WCF will automatically pick it up, correct?

Comment: An interesting tidbit I found from your link: "If no default format is specified on the operation, the value of the DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat property is used." So basically, if the poster doesn't specify the content type, and there's no RequestFormat on the operation, it will actually pick up the format from the defaultOutgoingResponseFormat. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `automaticFormatSelectionEnabled` property to **`true`** in *webHttp* element in **web.config file**

```
<behaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior>
         <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

eg: you can set `Accept:application/json` in recieving end and get JSON result.

postman screens

[image: Json response]

====================================================================

[image: Xml response]

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510(v=vs.110).aspx